# Limitar columnas a importar con maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, excel

Estoy realizando la importación de un archivo excel con la librería `maatwebsite/excel` en su ultima versión y `Laravel 6.0`, el archivo consta de la siguiente cabecera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, debo tomar hasta la columna final de grupo, pero obvio la libreria al armar el array de datos como las columnas tienen el mismo nombre, toma siempre los de personal porque no pueden haber keys con el mismo nombre en un mismo nivel de array, entonces los valores me aparecen mal al momento de importar.

Esta es una muestra del row que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden notar los valores los esta tomando de las ultimas 4 filas

En la versión anterior de la librería cuando se utilizaba el método load permitía especificar un limite de columnas con: `$reader->limitColumns(4)`, pero ahora en la nueva versión no consigo la forma de hacer esto.

Lo que estoy buscando es limitar la cantidad de columnas antes de realizar la importación del archivo, me he leído la documentación y he investigado en otras fuentes y no he conseguido solución. Lo que he intentado es escuchar el evento `BeforeImport` dentro de mi clase `Import`, pero hasta ahi he llegado sin saber como limitar las columnas dentro del evento.

Aquí la forma en la que estoy usando la clase Import

```
 //controller
 public function produccion(Request $request)
 {
     Excel::import(new TopProduccionImport($request->all()), $request->file('excel'));
 }

 //clase Import

 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
 use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeImport;

 class TopProduccionImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
 {

     //use Importable, RegistersEventListeners;

     protected $client_id;

     public function __construct($data)
     {
         $this->client_id = $data['client'];
     }

     public static function beforeImport(BeforeImport $event) : array
     {

     }

     /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
     public function collection(Collection $rows)
     {
        foreach ($rows as $value => $row) {
            //aquí iría el código que utilizo para insertar los datos
        }
     }

     public function headingRow(): int
     {
         return 2;
     }
}
```

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta tu clase Import y cómo la estás llamando

Comment: He agregado la clase Import @porloscerrosΨ gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Y en esa parte que dice `//aquí iría el código que utilizo para insertar los datos` no tienes control sobre qué columna de cada fila estás importando?

Comment: No, alli solo tengo el row con todos los datos de la fila. El problema es que como muestro en la pregunta, el nombre de la columna B, C, D, es la misma que la E, F, G porque el nombre de esas columnas son en este formato m/Y pero solo necesito tomar la B,C y D. Ya que cuando la libreria arma el array de datos por existir keys con el mismo nombre por default toma las ultimas columnas. Quiere decir que ya en el $rows que recorro llega mal el array de datos

Comment: Y qué haces cuando recorres `$rows`? Insertas en la base de datos? Según la [ducumentación](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html) puedes hacer un forech sobre `$rows` y acceder a las columnas de cada `$row` por el índice. Ej: `$row[0]`, `$row[1]`, etc

Comment: He editado la pregunta, colocando unas imagenes de ejemplo para que pueda visualizar mejor. Puedo acceder a cada una de las columnas por el indice, pero como muestro en las imagenes, ya antes de recorrerlo viene mal la data

Comment: Necesitas la cabeceras para algo o puedes ignorarlas? Si no necesitas realmente las cabeceras, tal vez sea mejor **no** usar la fila de cabeceras como índices, y usar el índice numérico como te mencioné en el comentario anterior. Al no usar el concern `WithHeadingRow`, puedes omitir la primeras filas con el concern `WithStartRow`. (https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/imports/concerns.html#import-concerns).

Comment: Hola¿Si pudiste solucionar tu problema?, yo me encuentro en la misma situación y no encuentro  la respuesta a mi problema

Comment: Hola @JesusSh, si la solución fue no utilizar el WithHeadingRow, y accediendo a los datos a través de $row[0] y así sucesivamente según lo que necesitaba

Comment: Lo intentare, por cierto otra pregunta, ¿hay forma de configurar la columna de inicio de donde va a empezar a importar ? ya que si se puede escoger la columna final, pero no puedo setear la columna de inicio

Comment: @JesusSh creo que te refieres a la fila por donde empezar a importar